# What is the word for wanting something bad to happen to make life exciting?

Tags: single-word-requests, emotions

In a book I am writing, a girl wants to have PTSD or abuse so her life is exciting. Like, she wants to live in a book or TV show trope. What is the word for wanting a little kink in a boring life to throw you off-course?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can call PTSD "a little kink in a boring life". There's a difference between wanting a little excitement and wanting major trauma. What point on that spectrum are you wanting this to be?

Comment: This overlaps with the broader sense of masochism. Surely nobody really wants to suffer; people do do unwise things to escape the humdrum ... and usually realise they've jumped out of the frying-pan into the fire.

Comment: If it's a propensity for high-speed or risky activities, it would be a *need for adrenaline*. Let's taste the spice of life!

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Munchausen's syndrome](https://www.nhsinform.scot/illnesses-and-conditions/mental-health/munchausens-syndrome#:~:text=Munchausen%27s%20syndrome%20is%20a%20rare,about%20his%20exploits%20and%20past.) - *a rare psychological and behavioural condition in which somebody fabricates or induces symptoms of illness in themselves.* We're more likely to hear/read about *Munchausen's syndrome **by proxy***, perhaps because the implications are more chilling. But Google Bard is unable to tell me which of MS and MSbP is more prevalent overall, because they're both often undiagnosed.

Comment: Thrill seeking, risk taking behaviour.

Comment: As Graffito – needs a bit of spice in her life.

Comment: The premise is unrealistic – I've never heard of anyone *wanting* to "have PTSD". Perhaps she just needs a bit of **adventure** in her life.

Comment: *Immaturity* perhaps?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not a psychologist, but I think Munchausen's is more about fabricating symptoms to gain sympathy, not actually wanting the bad things to happen. It's probably closer to hypochondria than what the OP describes.

Comment: A drama queen? Does she want to suffer for her art? Or is she actually dysfuctional?

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the commenters above that you might consider rephrasing the emotion a little more sensitively—"want[ing] to have PTSD or abuse" reads more like a psychological disorder than a character trait—I think a word that suits what you're looking for is **ennui**.

[From the OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/ennui_n):

> a. The feeling of mental weariness and dissatisfaction produced by want of occupation, or by lack of interest in present surroundings or employments.

See the 1758 quote in the definition above:

> In less than a month, the man, used to business, found that living like a gentleman was dying of ennui.